# Как создать css анимацию точки, а с нее выводится линия?

Tags: css, css3, анимация, css-animation, svg-animation

Есть такие блоки http://prntscr.com/mxaqw4, разной высоты/ширины, как можно сделать с помощью css анимацию, чтобы появлялась сначала точка, а с нее потом выводилась линия?

Comment: вы полный скриншот покажите ...а то интересно что должно получится в итоге

Comment: Вы можете анимировать путь в svg. Получится примерно так: https://codepen.io/ReHaze/pen/RdvbjN